# POM for org.jivesoftware:smack:jar:3.4.1-0cec571 is missing

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, smack

I've some java files for gcm-server in java. I'd like to combine them into a jar file. I'm trying to do that in maven (just learning), but I get the following error.
the structure of the directory is:

```
--src   
| --main
|   --java
|     --server
|       "my java files here"
--pom.xml
```

Error:

```
The POM for org.jivesoftware:smack:jar:3.4.1-0cec571 is missing, no dependency information available
```

the pom.xml used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gcm.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcm-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <!-- tag::joda[] -->
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jivesoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1-0cec571</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- end::joda[] -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas on resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jivesoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1-0cec571</version>
  </dependency>
```

with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jivesoftware/smack the artifact was moved. It looks like the artifactId also changed form smack to smack-core and friends.

Comment: Could not find artifact org.igniterealtime.smack:smack:jar:3.4.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2). But if I use 3.2.1, it works good.

Comment: Ahh, yes sorry, I thought I put 3.4.1 on Maven Central. You should use the latest stable version of Smack, which is 4.1.3 at the time of writing. *&Do not use any Smack version < 4.0**, as [those versions have some security issues.](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0363). And if you really must use a a version < 4.0, then don't use 3.2.1, as it's pretty old (~5 years), instead include the Smack 3.4.1 jar in your project.

Comment: Edited again to point to 4.1.3 but also changing artifactId from smack to smack-core.